# ERC721 NFTs minted at contract's creation via ERC2309 do not appear in safe's assets

Tags: nft, gnosis-safe

ERC721A supports minting NFTs at contract's creation (with ERC2309), but Gnosis safe's UI doesn't seem to display them.
For example, NFT ID 0 to 499 of contract `0x7777777be27646da6603804ce7202224121a2482` are owned by the safe multi-sig `0x641e70d310BB12136D2e967F1f55F43ac02dd4BC`, but in the UI, only NFTs received much later appear.

What can we do to fix this?

Comment: It's a frontend thing because ERC2309 isn't friendly to off-chain indexers. You'll see the same issue in some marketplaces. My advice would be to contact the Gnosis team in their Discord, and to interact with the smart-contract directly in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks! Tried their support, the person wasn't very tech savvy so it didn't go anywhere, the discord says to ask here, do you know how I could escalate this?

Comment: I guess you could try to contact https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/60740/richard